# Implementing a heap: becomes inaccurate after one sift

Tags: java, arrays, heap

I am currently trying to write a program that takes an array and makes it into a heap.
I am trying to implement a siftDown method that will take the elements of the array and make them into a heap but i am just not getting the correct output i want and im not sure why:

```
public void makeHeap(int[] arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)//for each element in the array, we we check its children and sift it down
    {
        siftDown(arr, i);
    }
}

//insert a new root in the correct position. Byu comparing the top element and swapping it with its largest child.
public void siftDown(int[]heap, int i)
{
    int c = i * 2; //grab the children of the current index we are at.

    if(c == 0) // 0*2 is 0 so we make it 1 so it will register the first nodes parents
    {
        c+=1;
    }

   if(c >= heap.length || c+1 >= heap.length) // so we dont go off the end of the array
    {
        return;
    }

    if(heap[c] < heap[c + 1]) //Is child 1 less than child 2? 
    {
        c += 1; //if it is we want c to be the greater child to eventually move upwards
    }

    if(heap[i] < heap[c])//If the parent we have just gotten is smaller than the child defined last loop, then we swap the two. We then call sift down again to compare child and parent.
    {
        heap = swap(heap,i,c);//swap the values
        siftDown(heap, c);//call again to compare the new root with its children.
    }

}
```

Here is my swap method:

```
 public int[] swap(int[]heap, int i, int c)
  {

    //capture the two values in variables
    int ele1 = heap[i];
    int ele2 = heap[c];
    
    heap[i] = ele2;//change heap i to heap c
    heap[c] = ele1;//change heap c to heap i
    
    return heap;
    
  }
```

The starting numbers are: 4,7,9,6,3,1,5
. The output i want to get is 9,7,5,6,3,1,4 but i seem to only be able to get 9,7,4,6,3,1,5. It seems once 4 gets sifted down once after being replaced by 9, the algorithm goes out of wack and it believes that 3 and 1 are its children when 1,5 should be.
Thank you or your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int c = i * 2; //grab the children of the current index we are at.

    if(c == 0) // 0*2 is 0 so we make it 1 so it will register the first nodes parents
    {
        c+=1;
    }
```

This looks wrong to me.
The heap indices for children should be a general formula that works for all cases.

```
Given parentIdx in 0-based array,
leftChildIdx = parentIdx * 2 + 1
rightChildIdx = parentIdx * 2 + 2
```

This means children of 0 are 1 and 2, children of 1 are 3 and 4, children of 2 are 5 and 6, etc.  It works.

Your code places children of 1 at 2 and 3, which is clearly wrong.